# What's thedifference between comparing object.constructor to its constructor and instanceof?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, instance, ecmascript-5

Lets say I have a Dog constructor

```
function Dog(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

And I have an instance of that constructor

```
const myDog = new Dog('Charlie');
```

As far as I learned recently, there are two ways to check if myDog is an instance of Dog:

1.

```
console.log(myDog instanceof Dog) //true
```

2.

```
console.log(myDog.constructor === Dog) //true
```

My question is, what are the differences between the two, which one is better and why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is pretty simple. Check out [MDN's documentation of instanceOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof). If you have an instance `Fido` that is an instance of `GreatDane` which is an instance of `Dog` which is an instance of `Object`, the following will be the case:

```
Fido instanceof GreatDane // true
Fido instanceof Dog // true
Fido instanceof Object // true
Fido.constructor === GreatDane // true
```

However, the following will not be true:

```
Fido.constructor === Dog // false
Fido.constructor === Object // false
```

So you can see the `instanceOf` keyword travels up the lineage, where `constructor` is looking at the actual function that created your instance.

Neither is better. It depends on your situation. What do you want to know about each object?

As Patrick Roberts points out in the comment below, `Fido.constructor` would be the actual constructor function inherited from `GreatDane`. And you are able to modify it, so if you ever changed the constructor, your comparison would then return `false`.

Comment: Not that it would be common-case but one disadvantage of the `constructor` check is that `constructor` is a writable property, so at any point that could be reassigned to an arbitrary value not relating to the object's _actual_ constructor.